# fn:sum error "cannot cast to xs:double"

Tags: xpath, casting, sum, xquery

I'm trying to add up multiple nodes (names & amount of nodes uncertain).

performing the query

```
for $x in //onboard/*
return $x
```

returns this (and more)

```
<total>
    <one/>
</total>
<total>
  <one>124</one>
  <two>1</two>
  <three>0</three>
</total>
<total>
  <one>46</one>
</total>
<total>
  <one>129</one>
  <two>1</two>
  <three>0</three>
</total>
<seafarers>
  <one>149</one>
  <two>3</two>
  <three>3</three>
  <six>155</six>
</seafarers>
<soldiers>
  <one>135</one>
  <six>118</six>
</soldiers>
```

per child of which its name is 'total' or 'seafarers' or something similar but not fixed I would like to return the sum of the values of all nodes from node 'one' to node 'six'
Again, it is unsure how many nodes there are and if any of them exist (for each node at least 1 number node exists, but this does not have to be 'one').

So far everything I have tried results in typecast errors or incorrect answers.

For the sample code provided, the desired answer would be:

```
125
46
130
310
253
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
for $x in //onboard/*[*]
return sum($x/*)
```

That reads : for `$x` as each child of `<onboard>` having at least one child element, return sum of all children element of `$x`.

**UPDATE :**

Turned out that the problem was due to empty element(s) passed to `sum()` function. This is another possible way to avoid the error :

```
for $x in //onboard/*[normalize-space()]
return sum($x/*[normalize-space()])
```

Above xquery only consider children of `<onboard>` that is *non-empty* element. Then in the `sum()` operation, again only non empty child of `$x` considered.

Comment: thank you for your answer for I am still quite desperate, but this still returns me the "cannot cast to xs:double" error

Comment: @Koen hmm.. what xquery engine do you use? I can't reproduce the error in http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery

Comment: I use the basex processor

Comment: I think I fixed it because some <one/> nodes were messing up my life with the following line: where not(data($x/*) = "")

Comment: I see. Having that self-closing element now I can reproduce the error, and eventually proposed a solution, check it out :)